# ionic 2 navigation bar

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to add some buttons inside the navigation bar for my app, 
[image]

```html
<ion-header>

    <ion-navbar hideBackButton #detailsNav style="height:70px" [formGroup]="detailsForm">

        <!--<ion-title>-->
            <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:20%;">
                        <button ion-button outline style="height:28px;font-size:12px" (click)="onCancel()">Cancel</button>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:60%;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;">
                        <div>Details Edit</div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:20%;">
                        <button ion-button style="height:28px;font-size:12px" (click)="onSubmit()" [disabled]="!detailsForm.valid">Save</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <!--</ion-title>-->

    </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```

When i am runing the app on android it works fine, but on an IPhone when I press the cancel button and navigate to the previous page the header will be visibile over the previous page header for a while

[image]

If I put the table inside the **ion-title** tag it will work fine, but it wont take all of the available width, again this only happens on IPhone. 
Is there any way to do this without having this lag?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ion-header>
   <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons start>
       <button ion-button outline (click)="onCancel()">
        Cancel
       </button>
     </ion-buttons>
     <ion-title>Details Edit</ion-title>
     <ion-buttons end >
       <button ion-button (click)="onSubmit()" [disabled]="!detailsForm.valid"">
         Save
       </button>
     </ion-buttons>
   </ion-toolbar>
 </ion-header>
```

Check out the documentation for more details [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#toolbar-buttons)